# Using a JSON user object for Authentication in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, authentication

So I've got an question about authentication and have been wondering how other people might handle this situation.  I'm currently running an Angular app that is built on a Rails API.

So far for authentication I have a form that does a post to the Rails side which logs the user in and then sends them back to the Angular app on success.  Once the cookie is set and the user is logged in, I'm able to access a user.json file which contains all the User information one might expect (Id, username, roles, rights, etc). Since verification all happens on Rails, if the user logs out then this information is removed.  So the two states look like so...

**Logged in**

```
{
id: 99384,
name: "Username",
url: "//www.test.com/profiles/Username",
timezone: null,
rights: [ ],
roles: [
"admin"
],
}
```

**Logged out**

```
{
error: "You need to login or join before continuing."
}
```

So far I've seen all these millions of different ways to do auth for Angular, but it seems like nothing fits this type of method.  So my question is, since the server is handling all of the verification, is there a way to just check if they user.json file is empty (displaying the error message) and if it is send the Angular app to the Rails login page?  Is there really any point messing with Cookies, Tokens, etc when I can base it all on the JSON file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using cookies - the server is setting them. What you have done is a fairly standard way of doing things.

To check the json file, you can do something like this stub shows in your controller:

```
app.controller('AppControl', function($scope, $http, $location){

    // Get the JSON file.

    $http.get('/path/to/json/file')

    .then(response){

      if(response.data.error){
        // redirect to login
        $location.path('login');

      }

      else{

        $scope.user = response.data;
        // your app code here.

      }

    })

    .catch(function (error){
      // unable to reach the json file - handle this.
    });

});
```

Of course, you should really move this out into a service so you can re-use it, and also  cache the data, rather than getting the user every time you change route/page, but this gives you a vague idea.

**EDIT** Example factory:

```
.factory('User', function( $http ){

  // Create a user object - this is ultimately what the factory will return.
  // it's a singleton, so there will only ever by one instance of it.
  var user = {};

  // NOTE: I am assigning the "then" function of the login promise to 
  // "whenLoggedIn" - your controller code is then very easy to read.
  user.whenLoggedIn = $http.get('user.json')

    .then(function(response){

      // Check to see if there is an error.
      if (response.data.error !== undefined) {
        // You could be more thorough with this check to determine the 
        // correct action (examine the error)
        user.loggedIn = false;

      }

      else {
        // the user is logged in
        user.loggedIn = true;
        user.details = response.data;

        return user;

      }        
    }).then; // <-- make sure you understand why that .then is there.

  return user;

})
```

**Usage in the controller**

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, User){

  // It's handy to have the user on the scope - you can use it in your markup
  // like I have with ng-show on index.html.
  $scope.User = User;

  // Do stuff only if the user is loggedin.
  // See how neat this is because of the use of the .then function
  User.whenLoggedIn( function (user){

    console.log(user.details.name + " is logged in");

  });


});
```

Because it's on the scope, we can do this in the html:

```
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <h1 ng-show="User.loggedIn == null">Logging in..</h1>
  <h1 ng-show="User.loggedIn == true">Logged in as {{ User.details.name }}</h1>
  <h1 ng-show="User.loggedIn == false">Not logged in</h1>
</body>
```

Here is an [example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tFJ56vp0DetnwSusOwz3?p=preview) where this is working.

Note the following:

- If the user is/was already logged in, when you inject the service in the future, it won't check the file again. You could create other methods on the service that would re-check the file, and also log the user out, back in, etc. I will leave that up to you.
- There are other ways to do this - this is just one possible option!
- This might be obvious, but it's always worth saying. You need to primarily handle authentication and security on the server side. The client side is just user experience, and makes sure the user doesn't see confusing or conflicting screens.

Comment: Thanks so much! So as I understand it though, I'm not really using ngCookies to verify the logged in state because I don't really need to?  Also, you mention using this as a service; how would this affect the fact that on some pages I don't care if the user is logged in, but on others I need to check for Auth?  Am I injecting this service into UI-Router?  Any examples of this?  Sorry for all the questions....

Comment: No problem - if it helps, upvote/accept :). You're not using `ngCookies`, and no, you don't need to - just do that on the server side. For the service part - inject the servers into the controllers of the pages that require authentication. Check the user before you do anything, and if the user is not populated, do your redirect.

Comment: Can't upvote yet :( but I will accept.  Final question and then I'll be out of your hair.  How would the factory be set up in terms of how you set up the example controller?  So far I've just set up simple factorys for pulling in JSON info and displaying in a controller.  P.S.  Thanks so much for helping the new guys....

Comment: updated with an example factory. It's really the bare minimum - but hopefully it will give you the right starting point.

Comment: Truly amazing help Ed.  Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the second `then` for?

Comment: Hi @Drew -  it's basically for readability when using the service in a controller. It means we're assigning that then function to `whenLoggedIn` on the service,  which means you can write `User.whenLoggedIn( // do stuff here) `. An alternative would be to call the method something like `ensureLoggedIn`,  and to exclude that `.then` and use `User. EnsureLoggedIn().then( // do stuff)`. Just make sure it's easy to understand when you read your code to prevent mistakes.